# cmake c++11 flag not included when makefile is generated

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile, cmake

I have the following **CMakeLists** file:

```
#################
# Com   Project # 
#################
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6)
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH /home/loay/Desktop/V5)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")
PROJECT (Sync)

FIND_PACKAGE (OpenSplice REQUIRED)

#####################
# Modele de donnees #
#####################

SET (idls 
 Communication.idl
)

# Extraction des fichiers a partir du .idl
execute_process(COMMAND idlpp -S -l cpp ./Communication.idl)

FOREACH(idl ${idls})
    OpenSplice_IDLGEN (${idl})
    STRING (REGEX REPLACE "\(.*\).idl" "\\1.cpp" VARS_1 ${idl})
    STRING (REGEX REPLACE "\(.*\).idl" "\\1.h" VARS_2 ${idl})
    STRING (REGEX REPLACE "\(.*\).idl" "\\1Dcps.cpp" VARS_3 ${idl})
    STRING (REGEX REPLACE "\(.*\).idl" "\\1Dcps.h" VARS_4 ${idl})
    STRING (REGEX REPLACE "\(.*\).idl" "\\1Dcps_impl.cpp" VARS_5 ${idl})
    STRING (REGEX REPLACE "\(.*\).idl" "\\1Dcps_impl.h" VARS_6 ${idl})
    STRING (REGEX REPLACE "\(.*\).idl" "\\1SplDcps.cpp" VARS_7 ${idl})
    STRING (REGEX REPLACE "\(.*\).idl" "\\1SplDcps.h" VARS_8 ${idl})
    STRING (REGEX REPLACE "\(.*\).idl" "ccpp_\\1.h" VARS_9 ${idl})
    SET(OpenSplice_SYNC ${OpenSplice_SYNC} ${VARS_1} ${VARS_2} ${VARS_3} ${VARS_4} ${VARS_5} ${VARS_6} ${VARS_7} ${VARS_8} ${VARS_9})
ENDFOREACH(idl)

###########################
# Fichiers de code source #
###########################
SET (APP_SOURCES
 arduino.cpp
 Controller.cpp
 CheckStatus.cpp
 Controller.cpp
 ListenerReader.cpp
 main.cpp
 Publisher.cpp
 Subscriber.cpp
 rs232.c
)

# Inclure dossier des sources des librairies a linker
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
 ${OpenSplice_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

# Inclure dossier des binaires des librairies a linker
link_directories (
 ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}
)


#############################
# Construction des binaires #
#############################
SET (APP_EXE start)
SET (SYNC Sync)

ADD_EXECUTABLE (${APP_EXE} ${APP_SOURCES})
ADD_LIBRARY (${SYNC} SHARED ${OpenSplice_SYNC})

ADD_DEFINITIONS (
 ${OpenSplice_DEFINITIONS}
 ${DEFINITIONS}
)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (${SYNC} 
 ${OpenSplice_LIBRARIES}
)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (${APP_EXE}
 ${OpenSplice_LIBRARIES}
 ${SYNC} 
)
```

As you can see I added this line `SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")` to enable support for **ISO c++ 2011**. I run this command `cmake . -G "Unix Makefiles"` to generate the files I need and to generate the makefile.

The problem is that when I run `make` command it fails with the following error:

> error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

This is weired because I did include the flag. What makes things even weirder is that when I re-run `cmake . -G "Unix Makefiles"` this problem is solved and I am able to build my files with no error!

What could be the cause of this problem ?

Comment: Which compiler (with version) are you using?

Comment: @PaulFloyd gcc 4.8.5

Comment: OK, later versions of g++ default to C++ 14. 4.8.5 defaults to C++ 03.

Comment: @PaulFloyd thanks for the info

Comment: Do you have to support such ancient CMake as 2.6? Since version 3.1, CMake has the variable [`CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html) (plus related `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED` and `CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS`) which control this at native CMake level. With these, you wouldn't have to go through flags manually.

Comment: @Angew Yes I have to support cmake 2.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably it's being overwritten somewhere else, since this CMake file is not official from PrismTech. Change that command to this:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

and put it at the end of your cmake file.

Comment: That worked thanks! Why do I have to put it at the end of the file ? I tried putting it at the begging at first but it didn't work, why ?

Comment: @LoayAshmawy First, notice that your `set` command overwrites all previous `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, unlike the one I provided, which appends to it. Like I said, this is not an official CMake file from PrismTech. Some guy created it. Probably he does exactly like you somewhere and overwrites `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, which will effectively result in removing that `c++11` flag you put at the beginning. When you add this to the end of the file, you'd be appending to whatever he did before.

Answer (score 2):

There are differences when set compiler flags before or after `project()` call.

1. When set flags **before** `project()` call you normally **redefine** default ones:

   ```
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT "<new-value>" CACHE STRING
      "Flags used by the compiler during all build types.")
   # ... some other assignments may be here ...
   project(<project-name>)
   ```

   **Note** `_INIT` suffix for the variable: actually flags are initialized *at the moment* of `project()` call, and *CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT* provides default value for them.
2. When set flags **after** `project()` call you normally **append** to default or user-supplied ones:

   ```
   project(<project-name>)
   # ...
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} <additional-value>")
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the info !!